# Reduce UI Automation Test Time in Android

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

I wrote a UI Automation test using UI Automator. Here are the test steps.

1. Open My App
2. Open Settings
3. Click Advance Features(Samsung Only)
4. Enable Finger Sensor Gesture
5. Open Recent Apps
6. Open My App

This whole automation test takes 8-7 seconds. Is there any workaround to reduce this test time to 4-5 seconds or is there any framework other than UI Automator that would execute these steps in less time. Apk installation takes 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

UI tests from its nature take longer to execute, because they replicate real user behaviour.

I would suggest to profile your methods to see how long it takes particular step and optimise if needed, but I don't think that will be the case.